# Can I use an Elastic IP with Cloudfront in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, elastic-ip

We want to use Cloudfront in our AWS infrastructure. The question is if is it possible to have the **same** Elastic IP that we use now in an EC2 instance. Or do we have to switch to Cloudfront IPs?

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to do this? Have you hard-coded an IP address somewhere? (Never a good idea.)

Answer (score 5):

CloudFront is a distributed system. You cannot assign an IP addresses to CloudFront. Do not use the IP addresses of CloudFront Edge locations. You need to use the domain name that CloudFront assigns to your distribution.

[Routing Traffic to an Amazon CloudFront Web Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html)

Comment: To extend this answer... Amazon CloudFront has over 100 edge locations. Resolving the DNS Name of the CloudFront distribution will point to an IP address in an appropriate one of those locations. Thus, trying to use a single IP address totally defeats the purpose of using CloudFront.

Comment: Plus the IP address of an edge location can change over time. Edge locations do not have static permanent addresses.

Comment: The Elastic IP could work as a "wild" card IP. And I'm asking if there's the technology to have everywhere the same IP no matter the geolocation issues. Apparently not...

Comment: What you are looking for is called "Anycast". This is not offered by AWS for CloudFront. Anycast would not be better than Amazon's edge location strategy. Anycast is a routing technology, AWS brings the caching to the edge closest to the customer plus higher performance network infrastructure from the edge to the AWS services using internal high speed networks. Anycast does not offer those features.

Comment: Nope! Actually, I'm looking for a CDN. I checked in AWS because we have all our infrastructure on it. I was hoping that CloudFront will offer such a solution because is deeply integrated with and optimized to work with popular AWS services.